# Vue Test passes, but this warning is displayed: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex, mount, vue-test-utils

I'm testing for the existence of 3 Subcomponents inside a Component. The test passes, but this warning is shown:

```
(node:52604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
(node:52604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:52604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the code of the Test:

```
  const localVue = createLocalVue();
  localVue.use(TPlugin(url)); //EDIT: ADD PLUGIN
  localVue.use(Vuex);

  it('WIP Fixing. Check the 3 Sub-Components of ChatWindow', () => {
    const onClose = jest.fn();
    const onMinimize = jest.fn();

    const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state: {
        title: "My Web Chat",
        titleIconUrl: "",
        visibility: "minimized",
        showCloseButton: false

      },
      getters: {
        title: (state) => state.title,
        lastName: (state) => state.lastName,
        state: (state) => state.visibility
      }
    })

    const wrapper = shallowMount(ChatWindow, {
      propsData: {
        onClose, 
        onMinimize
      },
      store,
      localVue
    })

    expect(wrapper.findComponent(Header).exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.findComponent(MessageList).exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.findComponent(UserInput).exists()).toBe(true)
  });
```

There must be some mistake in the way I mount the component with Vuex, any ideas?

UPDATE, here is an extract from my index.js:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       title: "My funky title",
       url: DEFAULT_URL,
       visibility: "minimized",
       //more variables....
    },
    mutations: {
       title(state, newTitle) {
            state.title = newTitle
        },
       url(state, newUrl) {
            state.url = newUrl
        },
       visibility(state, visibility) {
            state.visibility = visibility
        },
       //more variables...
    }
    getters: {
       title: state => state.title,
       url: state => state.url,
       visibility: visibility => state.visibility,
       //more variables.....
       state: state => {
            return { 'visibility': state.visibility }
        },
    }
})


window['TWChat'] = {
  initialize(element, twcProps) {
    Vue.prototype.$store = store;

    if (twcProps.title) {
      store.commit('title',twcProps.title);
    }

    ///more similar if/commit blocks...
    // check required properties
    if (!store.getters.url) {
      // TODO: thow error if url is missing?
      return
    }

    Vue.use(TPlugin(store.getters.title));
    Vue.prototype.$extensionMethods = functionMap;

    //TChat is the parent of ChatWindow, the componentent of the Test 
    above.
    new Vue({
      render: (h) => h(TChat, { props: { } }),
    }).$mount(element);
  }
}
```

index.ejs code:

```
<div id="t-chat"></div>
<script src="t-chat.js"></script> -->
    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
 
        var element = document.getElementById('t-chat');
        const someProps = {
          'url': '<%= process.env.ENDPOINT_URL %>',
          'title':'<%= process.env.HEADER_TITLE %>'
        }

        window.TChat.initialize(element, someProps);
      }
     </script>
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your `main.js` file?

Comment: @sebasaenz sure, I made an edit.

Comment: @sebasaenz By the way, that's the real index.js, I guess I don't need a mock of it.